# What Does the `type:` Configuration in a Symfony Route Configuration Control?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

What does the `type:` configuration in a Symfony routing file control?  What are its valid values?

I can't find this configuration field explicitly documented anywhere.  It's referenced indirectly in Symfony's [routing documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html).

```
app_directory:
    resource: '../legacy/routing/'
    type:     directory
```

and seems related to loading in additional routes.  However, its behavior (or all its allowed values) doesn't seem to be explicatly defined anywhere.  I can make a guess that it somehow tells Symfony *how* to load the external routes, but I'd love to know

1. Is my guess correct?
2. Are there valid values other than `directory` or `annotation`?
3. Is this formally documented anywhere?
4. Is there a spot in the Symfony internals that would be a good place to start finding these answers for myself?

Answer (score 1):

You can find how the type works in the Symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/external_resources.html), see code below. It controls if the routes should be loaded from the PHP annotations or the YAML or XML files found in that (bundle) directory.

```
app_file:
    # loads routes from the given routing file stored in some bundle
    resource: '@AcmeOtherBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml'

app_annotations:
    # loads routes from the PHP annotations of the controllers found in that directory
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    type:     annotation

app_directory:
    # loads routes from the YAML or XML files found in that directory
    resource: '../legacy/routing/'
    type:     directory

app_bundle:
    # loads routes from the YAML or XML files found in some bundle directory
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/public/'
    type:     directory
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention @Paweł, +1 -- however, per the question, the main text of the linked document doesn't really fully document what `type` does -- it just lists two possible examples of values.  I'm looking for something more concrete and comprehensive.